# Search data from mth to nth row in Redis Server using ServiceStack.Redis C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, redis, servicestack

I have Redis server with 1000s of Customer rows in the data key `[urn:Customer]`. 
I need to fetch paged results from this record set for my auto complete process.

My code:

```cs
var custDetails = from C in nwDB.Customers
                  select new { 
                      C.CustomerID, C.CompanyName, 
                      C.ContactName, C.City, 
                      C.Country, C.PostalCode, 
                      C.Phone, C.Fax 
                  };

using (var redis = new RedisClient())
{
    redis.FlushDb();
    redis.FlushAll();

    var RedisUsers = redis.As<CustomerR>();
    RedisUsers.SetSequence(0);

    foreach (var eachCustomer in custDetails)
    {
        RedisUsers.Store(new CustomerR
        {
            RedisCustID = RedisUsers.GetNextSequence(),
            CustomerID = eachCustomer.CustomerID,
            CompanyName = eachCustomer.CompanyName,
            ContactName = eachCustomer.ContactName,
            City = eachCustomer.City,
            Country = eachCustomer.PostalCode,
            Phone = eachCustomer.Phone,
            Fax = eachCustomer.Fax
        });
    }

    var allThepeople = RedisUsers.GetAll();
    gvCustomers.DataSource = allThepeople;
    gvCustomers.DataBind();
}
```

Instead of `GetAll()`, I need to display only top 50 rows using the`RedisUsers.GetNextSequence()` value.

Comment: What is your *question*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use a key per customer

It would be best if you stored each customer as their own key. *i.e.* `urn:Customer:123` would represent `CustomerID` = 123.

This gives us the advantage of being able to access the customer by their Id simply by selecting that key. But it also allows us to `SCAN` the keys that match the Customer key pattern. i.e. `urn:Customer:<id>`.

You can also avoid creating an arbitrary `RedisCustID`, just use the `CustomerID`, it will save a lot of confusion.

## To store the customers:

```cs
var custDetails = from c in nwDB.Customers select new { 
    c.CustomerID, 
    c.CompanyName, 
    c.ContactName, 
    c.City, 
    c.Country, 
    c.PostalCode, 
    c.Phone, 
    c.Fax
};

using (var redis = new RedisClient())
{
    var customers = redis.As<CustomerR>();

    foreach(var customer in custDetails)
    {
        // The key for this customer
        var customerKey = string.Format("Customer:{0}", customer.CustomerID);

        // Store the customer
        // Use ConvertTo<T> to auto map the properties
        customers.SetEntry(customerKey, customer.ConvertTo<CustomerR>());
    }
}
```

## To retrieve a customer by Id:

```cs
using (var redis = new RedisClient())
{
    var customers = redisClient.As<CustomerR>();
    var customerKey = string.Format("Customer:{0}", 123);
    var customer = customers.GetValue(customerKey);
}
```

## To retrieve all customers:

```cs
using (var redis = new RedisClient())
{
    var customerKeys = redis.ScanAllKeys("Customer:*").ToList();
    var allCustomers = redis.GetValues<CustomerR>(customerKeys);
}
```

## To retrieve the top 50 customers:

The `ScanAllKeys` method allows you to page the results, which is ultimately what you are looking to do.

```cs
using (var redis = new RedisClient())
{
    var customerKeys = redis.ScanAllKeys("Customer:*", 50).ToList();
    var top50Customers = redis.GetValues<CustomerR>(customerKeys);
}
```

## To retrieve customers between a certain range:

i.e. get page 3 of size 10

```cs
int page = 3;
int pageSize = 10;

int startAt = pageSize * page;
int endAt = startAt + pageSize;

using (var redis = new RedisClient())
{
    var pagedCustomerKeys = redis.ScanAllKeys("Customer:*", endAt).ToList().Skip(startAt).Take(pageSize);
    var pagedCustomers = redis.GetValues<CustomerR>(pagedCustomerKeys);
}
```

If you want to read about how to update a customer, or delete a customer [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24117809/1295344), which provides further examples.

I hope that helps.